# Get specific field from Uri

Tags: c#, url, uri

I'm using the following url and I need to delete the **?$format=xml** from the url. Is there a simple way to achieve this ?

```
Uri uri = new Uri("https://ldcorp:435/mtp/op/ota/ind/Customer/?$format=xml);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe with simple string methods:

```
uriString = uri.ToString();
int indexOfQuestionMark = uriString.IndexOf("?");
if(indexOfQuestionMark >= 0)
{
    uri = new Uri(uriString.Substring(0, indexOfQuestionMark));
}
```

or with the `Uri` class itself and `string.Format`:

```
string pathWithoutQuery = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", uri.Scheme,
    uri.Scheme, Uri.SchemeDelimiter, uri.Authority, uri.AbsolutePath);
uri = new Uri(pathWithoutQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks Tim,but the link path can be changed and more than one ? in the URL,I just need to find the ?$format=xml and delete it from the URL

Comment: @JeanTehhe: sorry, i haven't understood your comment.

Comment: HI Tim,the problem is that I can have in the URL more than one question mark and I dont need the last always just to delete from the url $format=xml,in addition the URL path can be changed having more slashes

Comment: @JeanTehhe: Then use `IndexOf` instead of `LastIndexOf` with the first approach. The second approach should work always. However, can a valid url really contain multiple question marks? `always just to delete from the url $format=xml` means that you want to remove only this url-parameter and nothing else?

Comment: HI Tim Im using the first option,assume that I dont have question mark   i got error ,how can i avoid it>

Comment: @JeanTehhe: You have to check that first: `int index = uriString.IndexOf("?"); if(index >= 0){// rest}`. I have edited my answer.